# ng-click not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs I have following code. For some reason `ng-click` is not triggering. I have seen various similar questions but I am not getting what wrong I am doing here. There is no error on the console as well. Thanks

**Controller**

```
.controller("eventsExample", function ($scope) {
        var technologies = [
                { techname: "Angularjs", likes: 0, dislikes: 0 },
                { techname: "Asp.net", likes: 0, dislikes: 0 },
                { techname: "JavaScript", likes: 0, dislikes: 0 },
                { techname: "HTML5/CSS3", likes: 0, dislikes: 0 }
        ];

        $scope.technologies = technologies;

        $scope.inscrementLikes = function (technology) {
            technology.Likes++;
        }

        $scope.inscrementDisLikes = function (technology) {
            technology.Dislikes++;
        }

    })
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="eventsExample">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Technology</th>
                <th>Likes</th>
                <th>Dislikes</th>
                <th>Hit Like/Dislike</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
                <td> {{technology.techname}} </td>
                <td> {{technology.likes}} </td>
                <td> {{technology.dislikes}} </td>
                <td> 
                    <input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="inscrementLikes(technology)" />
                    <input type="button" value="Dislike"  ng-click="inscrementDisLikes(technology)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Please create plunker or fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's typo here `technology.Likes++` and `technology.Dislikes++`.

Use lower case for likes and dislikes

Sample Pen:  [Sample](http://codepen.io/Diljohn5741/pen/jWGZrE)

Comment: Gotcha! that was silly mistake. Is there any IDE with intellisense to spot such syntax blunders?

Comment: I primarily use Webstorm. It does provide notification below any property or variable if it doesn't find such thing in context similar to how we get spelling mistakes on words in mails/documents. It also provides good intellisense with available options.